# Why did I fail to import a sub-module of an already-installed module (by pip)? How can I solve it?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I successfully installed a module called spirit by pip. The module itself can be imported, but the sub-moduls cannot be imported? How can I solve it?

```
from spirit import state
```

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-49c9d956fafb> in <module>
      1 import spirit
----> 2 from spirit import state

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\spirit\state.py in <module>
     40 
     41 ### Load Library
---> 42 _spirit = spiritlib.load_spirit_library()
     43 
     44 ### State wrapper class to be used in 'with' statement

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\spirit\spiritlib.py in load_spirit_library()
     25 
     26     ### Load the Spirit library
---> 27     _spirit = ctypes.CDLL(spirit_py_dir + '/' + libname)
     28 
     29     ### Return

D:\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    362 
    363         if handle is None:
--> 364             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    365         else:
    366             self._handle = handle

OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Comment: Please include the error message inside the post as text with a \`\`\` around it to format as a code block.

Comment: It looks like you're missing a dependency, probably a .dll file. Do you need to install something else first?

Comment: ...in many cases, you have to install the native (C/C++) version of a library as well as the Python module.  I know Sprit is a C/C++ library, but I don't know if installing the Python module automatically installs the C/C++ binary as well.  You might want to try installing the C/C++ library just to be sure you have it, as one way or the other, it has to be there for things to work right.

Comment: Maybe not. I followed the guidance on their website. They simply said "simply use pip install spirit". Anyway I will try to find if there's a .dll file. Thanks@101